# maximum number of possibility

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I need to get the max possible from array that has the quantity of each product.
In the calculation of possibilities, there must always be two products, it cannot be less or more.

```
// array products
$group_iten = array (1,1,4); // 6 units in 3 products

// max and min per product
$max_min_products = 2;

// my algorithm
$i = 0;
$c = 0;
$counter = 0;
while ( true ) {
    // Sorts array in place by values in descending order
    rsort($group_iten);
    
    if ( $c < $max_min_products ) {
        
        $group_iten[$i] -= 1;
        
        $i++;
        $c++;
        $counter++;
    }
    else {
        $c = 0;
        $i = 0;
    }
    
    if ( min($group_iten) == 0 ) {
        unset($group_iten[$i]);
    }
    
    if ( count($group_iten) < $max_min_products )
        break;
}
print_r($counter);
// result = 2

line output:
Array sorted:
        4, 1, 1
        3, 1, 0 ( 1 )
        2, 0, 0 ( 2 )
End;
result = 2

But with example array = [4, 4, 2];
        4, 4, 2 ( inital array )
        3, 3, 2  ( 1 )
        2, 2, 2  ( 2 )
        1, 1, 2  ( 3 )
        1, 0, 1  ( 4 )
        0,  , 0  ( 5 )
```

Expected: result 5, but my algorithm result 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// specific category of required products
$required_products = 2; // 2 types

// array list base mysql query 
$group_iten = array (4,4,2);

// order by descending, fix possible ORDER ASC. 
rsort($group_iten);

// possibility number counter
$i=0;

// if the number of items in the group is greater than the required amount of product
if ( count( $group_iten ) >= $required_products ) {
    
    // while the required quantity of item is greater than zero
    while ( $group_iten[$required_products-1] > 0 ) {
        
        // subtract from all possibility
        for ( $j = 0; $j <= ($required_products-1); $j++ )
            $group_iten[$j]--;
        
        // array order by desc
        rsort($group_iten);
        
        // count possibility
        $i++;
    }
}
echo  $i;

output : 5
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: additional information  : algorithm commented